# python imaplib - gmail cannot be accessed

Tags: python, gmail, imaplib, gmail-imap

I am trying to access and read emails from my gmail account using a python script and imaplib, but whenever I run, I receive this message from the terminal:
imaplib.error: b'[AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure)'

I've tried looking online everywhere, even on StackOverflow itself, and all if not most of the ways I found were outdated, or simply didn't work. I'm simply trying to login to my gmail through python, and since Google disabled the less secure access for third party apps, I can't fine the solution. Can someone here help me?

```
import imaplib
import email


username = 'myemail@gmail.com'
password = 'TheCorrectPassword'

mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com")


mail.login(username, password)
```

This is my code. I have boiled it down and simplified it to the root cause, which is the login part.

Comment: Generate an app password or implement OAUTH.

Comment: And I’m not sure app passwords are supported anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use app password instead of your Gmail password. To generate an app password, you need to set up 2FA for your account first.